# Is it possible to enable Dark Mode on Xcode 10 on High Sierra?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I downloaded xcode 10 beta and installed it on my macbook which is running on macOs 10.13.4 High Sierra. I tried to enable dark mode on xcode 10, but i could find how to do it ? Any suggestions, is it possible ?

upd: as i understand, xcode gets the system appearance value and renders in that mode, so it must be possible with some command in terminal

Comment: no its only available from `Mojave`

Comment: No. Mojave only

Comment: its not depend on Xcode version that you downloaded....its a new feature in `MacOS 10.13 Mojave`

Comment: I believe these other answers are incorrect, usually this would be a userdefaults setting which could theoretically be enabled via the Terminal. I am currently searching for the exact setting.

Comment: To follow up, I was able to artificially enable dark mode on MacOS 10.13, but the flag was not detected by Xcode. The parameter is the same for the System Preference's General's "Use dark menu bar and dock"

Answer (score 6):

is not related to your XCode its related to **macOS** , the feature available from  **10.14 Mojave onwards** , for detail info you get from [here](https://www.macworld.co.uk/news/mac-software/macos-10-14-mojave-3669087/)

**Mojave Release date**

> Apple said that the developer beta for all software would be made available on 4 June, while the public iOS 12 beta will be available later in June.

**Mojave: New features**

> In particular, Apple appears to have focused on enhancing the Finder and Quick Look. But other new features are welcome, in **particular Dark Mode**, which we will look at first

**Dark mode**

A Dark Mode is nothing new - there has been a Dark Mode available **since El Capitan**, but it only changed the appearance of menu bar and Dock. However, the new Dark Mode is what everyone had been calling for.

In **High Sierra**, Dark Mode adjusts the colour of the menu bar and dock, but little else. The Dock's translucent background becomes darker, the menu bar's drop-down menus are darker (although still translucent).

Not all third-party apps offer support for the dark menu bar, and even some Apple apps, such as Safari, currently feature a bright translucent sidebar.

The **Dark Mode in Mojave**, will be applied to all elements of the interface, in every app, system-wide. Users can choose whether to turn it on

**for enable and disable the Dark Mode** for reference purpose I taken the answer from [here](https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-enable-dark-mode-in-macos-mojave/)

**Short answer**

> click on  > System Preferences from the menu and choose General. Here choose the second option under ‘Appearance’ to toggle into dark mode, step by step tutorial you get [here](https://appletoolbox.com/2018/06/how-to-enable-dark-mode-and-dynamic-display-on-macos-mojave/)

## Step 1.

> Click on Apple Menu on your Mac

## Step 2.

> click on System Preference.

[image]

## Step 3.

> click on General.

[image]

## step 4.

> Next up, check out the **second option next to Appearance**. Simply select it to activate Dark Mode on your macOS.

[image]

**Disable the dark mode**

follow the above 3steps and finally deselect **the second option that’s right next to Appearance.**

[image]

Comment: Have you found out a way to change to dark mode automatically (e.g: à-la-night shift) ? Or form the terminal ?

Answer (score 5):

For those of you like me looking in 2020 who couldn't find how to enable dark mode even on dark-mode-supporting systems, it's super simple. **Just go to preferences -> general**. There you can set Xcode's appearance to always dark, always light, or system-dependant.

Answer (score 4):

You need to follow those steps:

1. Go to: https://developer.apple.com/download/
2. Install macOS Mojave 10.14 beta version.
3. Install Xcode 10 beta.
4. Go to System Preferences/General and change appearance to dark mode.
5. Then, you can work 24/7

[image: Now you. can work 24/7!]

Answer (score 2):

Not possible to fully in High Sierra but if you use macOS Mojave (10.14.+), you can enable dark mode only for Xcode 10 using this command line.

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSWindowDarkChocolate -bool true
```

Using this command line on lower version of macOS will partially break your Xcode interface.

(tested with High Sierra V10.13.4)

Comment: Can you define "partially break"?

Answer (score 1):

It'll become very ugly if you force to enable dark mode on High Sierra, and I have changed the color scheme before...

## global

defaults write -g NSWindowDarkChocolate -bool TRUE

## Xcode only

defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSWindowDarkChocolate -bool true

[image]

Comment: Same here !! ;)

Answer (score 0):

jw382 is a little confused about the Dark Mode, yes you can have a dark Mode, like Midnight, but not the new Xcode 10 beta Dark Mode, where everything is in a dark area.
Maybe this other like will help : [How do you change Xcode 10 Beta to the new "Darkmode"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50777039/how-do-you-change-xcode-10-beta-to-the-new-darkmode)

You need to install MoJave 10.14 beta to make you mac Dark Mode first.

Answer (score 0):

Only for **macOS Mojave 10.14** and onwards..

If you want to use Xcode in dark mode while maintaining a different system wide mode or generally modify the mode per app I can recommend *Gray* (https://github.com/zenangst/Gray). *Gray* is a simple tool providing an interface for application-specific user configurations.