# How do you change Xcode 10 Beta to the new "Darkmode"?

Tags: xcode, macos, developer-tools

I recently have updated to the new Xcode 10 Beta. I want to use the Darkmode but am confused because I cannot find the option. I'm still on macOS High Sierra just if your wondering. (My System: Mid 2012 Mac Pro)

Comment: I think it's a feature of the new MacOS version, Xcode only supports it.

Comment: Sulthan is right, you need to have macOS Mojave 10.14 beta for Xcode 10 Beta to show Dark Mode. When you install this new OS it also makes you mac have Dark Mode, hence why Xcode is in Dark Mode, probably, Not seen any options to change this via the Xcode platform. hope this helps.